# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de usar paginação e scroll infinito em sites?

Tags: aplicação-web, ux

O que o usuário ganha ou perde quando se escolhe um deles? Consequentemente o que proprietário do site tem algum ganho em função da melhor experiência do usuário.

Quando optar por cada um? Existe um tipo de site ou aplicação web que se adéqua melhor?

Entre as desvantagens tem algo que pode dar errado?

Eu sei que o ideal é conduzir estudos com o público alvo. Mas queria saber o que já se concluiu de forma geral sobre o tema.

Quanto mais referências puder fornecer, melhor. Não quero saber o que você gosta ou usa. Procuro informações objetivas de quem entende realmente do assunto.

Comment: Scroll é fundamental a única desvantagem que vejo é a demora no carregamento de imagens etc. e quando é preciso voltar ao top ou a um sub tema específico.

Comment: O problema de voltar ao topo ou escolher uma nova categoria pode ser sanado com um menu fixo, e também um botão acessível na lateral, indicando "voltar ao topo" - para que o usuário não precise voltar rolando novamente!

Comment: Desta forma terminam os problemas

Comment: A demora é relativo. Só porque tem imagens não significa que é demorado. [Veja a pesquisa de imagens do google, por exemplo](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=teste&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO1diLrfTRAhXGEZAKHUbGB78Q_AUICSgC&biw=1920&bih=919). Ela é mais rápida que muitos sites, e ela é somente imagens :p

Comment: Para o site ser rápido mesmo com imagens. Deve ser uma otimização e performance

Comment: Um artigo recente sobre isso: https://speckyboy.com/infinite-scrolling/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> O que o usuário ganha ou perde quando se escolhe um deles?
>   Consequentemente o que proprietário do site tem algum ganho em função
>   da melhor experiência do usuário.

Do ponto de vista do usuário: na paginação ele tem mais controle (ou, ao menos, sensação de controle) sobre o conteúdo, enquanto que na rolagem infinita o usuário tem menos esforço.

Imagine um cenário de um site tipo o Flickr, que contém apenas imagens, e em que o usuário está fazendo uma busca por uma imagem de algo desejado. Em certo momento ele encontra uma de que gosta, mas decide continuar procurando um pouco mais. Na paginação ele tem facilidade de memorizar onde está o item que gostou. Pode ser pela posição de uma barra de rolagem, pode ser pelo número da página, pode até mesmo ser pela posição relativa (número de cliques ou pagedowns dados). Isso já não é tão fácil na rolagem infinita.

Imagine que nesse mesmo cenário, as fotos exibem informações quando o mouse está posicionado sobre elas, que são importantes na decisão do usuário pelo item procurado. Nesse caso, ter de mover o mouse ou mesmo a mão do mouse para o teclado para controlar a rolagem gera mais esforço. Pode parecer pouco, mas dependendo do contexto (se for um profissional que passa o dia usando esse site) pode ser bastante cansativo ou reduzir a produtividade. Nesse sentido a rolagem infinita pode ajudar a reduzir o esforço.

Do ponto de vista do proprietário do site: na paginação ele dá o controle para o usuário, na rolagem infinita o proprietário conduz a experiência. O usuário deve ser sempre o foco de atenção ao se projetar a interação de qualquer produto, mas ainda assim essa decisão pode decorrer da experiência intencionada. Citaram em outras respostas a ideia de aumentar o tempo que a pessoa passa no site, por exemplo. A rolagem infinita gera essa sensação de que há muito mais por se ver, e por isso estimula o usuário permanecer mais tempo. Além disso, se por qualquer motivo não se deseja estimular o usuário a "voltar" (isto é, se deseja dar preferência para que ele veja conteúdo novo ao invés de conteúdo já visto), a rolagem infinita pode ser mais apropriada. Pode ser o caso de sites ou aplicações de notícias, como alternativa ao famoso serviço do tipo *Push*.

Uma solução híbrida é difícil porque dificulta a percepção de estado do usuário (mesmo que você use uma barra de rolagem, ela vai mudar de proporção conforme mais dados são exibidos) e requer muito mais memória do sistema porque essencialmente você vai ter que manter tudo em memória.

> Quando optar por cada um? Existe um tipo de site ou aplicação web que
>   se adéqua melhor?

No sentido do que foi discutido, a rolagem infinita talvez seja mais apropriada para sites em que o conteúdo é fugaz, existe em enorme quantidade, ou é gerado por diversas fontes distintas. Nas redes sociais, por exemplo, o conteúdo é produzido por outros usuários, comumente contém imagens, vídeos curtos ou links que são abertos ou "processados" imediatamente (o usuário lê, ri, se ofende ou curte, e passa para o próximo; links são abertos e lidos imediatamente ou guardados em outra aba, independente da paginação).

Caso contrário, provavelmente é melhor utilizar a paginação mesmo. :)

> Entre as desvantagens tem algo que pode dar errado?

Na rolagem infinita, do ponto de vista técnico tem a possibilidade do sistema simplesmente não conseguir exibir tudo o que o usuário quer ver. Isso pode ser contornado ao descartar os itens muito antigos lá do começo da rolagem, e é o que geralmente se faz ao meu ver. Na paginação, o problema potencial é desestimular o usuário. Se o resultado de uma busca for muito grande, ele pode não se interessar por usar. O Google é uma situação atípica porque apesar de ele mostrar um bestilhão de resultados o usuário sabe que os primeiros são os mais relevantes (por convenção e por costume, já que essa informação não é necessariamente explícita - isto é, não há um número com a relevância na frente de cada resposta).

> Eu sei que o ideal é conduzir estudos com o público alvo. Mas queria
>   saber o que já se concluiu de forma geral sobre o tema.

Essa é uma boa pergunta. Mas é difícil ter uma única resposta pra ela, porque depende do domínio de problema. Como vc mesmo aponta, o ideal é conduzir estudos com o público alvo, mas esse público muda dependendo da área. Na área de e-commerce, por exemplo, parece ser condizente com o que eu apontei anteriormente. Há [esse estudo](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/pagination-infinite-scrolling-load-more-buttons/) muito bem feito e que inclui também uma distinção entre a paginação e o uso de botões "Carregar Mais" (carregamento em partes). O resumo é dado lá no texto mesmo, e é o seguinte (em tradução livre):

"*Paginação ainda é a forma mais popular de carregar novos itens em um website porque já existe por padrão em quase todas as plataformas de e-commerce. Entretanto, nossos testes de usabilidade indicaram que botões “Carregar Mais” combinados com lazy-loading (carregamento preguiçoso) tendem a ser uma implementação superior, resultando em uma experiência mais contínua (sem costuras). Nós descobrimos que a rolagem infinita pode ser bastante prejudicial à usabilidade — em particular, na busca por resultados e em dispositivos móveis. Ainda assim, isso não é preto e branco, porque o desempenho de cada método varia de acordo com o contexto da página*."

Comment: E estas publicações que são carregadas por demanda através de script são também indexadas por sistemas de buscas? Sei que a paginação é, pois o sistema de busca identifica as várias URLs das páginas, mas sendo esta uma página única, aconteceria também?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Honestamente eu não sei responder à sua pergunta, colega. :) Não tenho quase nenhuma experiência com SEO. Mas imagino que funcione de maneira similar às indexadas. Afinal, mesmo na paginação as páginas são geradas dinamicamente de acordo com o conteúdo, certo? De todas as formas, eu entendi que o foco da pergunta era UX...

Answer (score 10):

#### O que é Scroll Infinito?

Scroll Inifino é uma forma de ter uma página infinita (se você possuir dados para isso, claro). Desta forma, à medida que o usuário chega ao final da página, novos registros serão adicionados automaticamente.

#### Vantagens

- Carrega o conteúdo definido sem necessitar de clicks do usuário;
- Não requer reajustes visuais, sendo o mesmo padrão de layout.
- O usuário não precisa entender do sistema para saber utilizar o recurso, basta ir ao final da página;
- Excelente experiência para dispositivos móveis;
- "prisão" do usuário no site.

#### Desvantagens

- Rodapé do site quase não será visto;
- Sem filtros para buscas, ou seja, caso queira salvar aquele "estado", poderá ter problemas;
- Sensação de "perda de controle" por parte do usuário;
- Possíveis problemas de performance por carregar muito conteúdo;

#### Quando utilizar?

Não existe uma *regra* para isso. Como você mesmo disse, a melhor forma seria realizar um estudo com o público alvo para definir o melhor cenário.

Dito isto, existem cenários onde o **Scroll Infinito** é mais utilizado, como em redes sociais, dando assim uma certa "graça" ao navegar pelo **Oceano de Informações** gerado pelos usuários em uma rede social.

Também é comum ser utilizado para lista de imagens, pois o padrão das informações dá uma sensação de conforto ao usuário quando ele recebe mais informações.

O próprio Google possui duas formas de paginações, o scroll infinito para [pesquisas de imagens](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=stack%20overflow%20em%20portugues&biw=1920&bih=919&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg5f25h_TRAhXGDpAKHYTxCuIQ_AUICSgE) e a paginação normal [para pesquisas Web](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=stack%20overflow%20em%20portugues&biw=1920&bih=919&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTxeK_h_TRAhUGmJAKHUp7D6QQ_AUIBygA&dpr=1).
Segundo [relatos](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-infinite-scroll-search-results-20862.html) o mesmo estaria pensando em alterar estas pesquisas para scroll inifito, mas não posso afirmar a veracidade da informação.

#### E sobre SEO?

O Google afirma que o scroll infinito pode ser utilizado pelo GoogleBot. Porém, deve ser levado alguns fatores na implementação. A lista de recomendações você pode ver no [webmastes.googleblog](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly.html).

#### Conclusão Pessoal

Eu particularmente acho elegante o uso de scroll infinito, mas em certas ocasiões.

Em redes sociais, lugares onde a paginação não é significante para mim ou para aplicativos mobiles, eu prefiro utilizar algo com o scroll infinito, pois me apresenta uma sensação melhor de usabilidade.

já em tabelas, notícias, blogs, sites institucionais, ou lugares com informações que contenham realmente leituras, eu prefiro ter o controle de conclusão, ou ao menos pensar que tenho esse controle.

#### Referências:

Bom, eu não sou ninguém para poder falar essas coisas, então abaixo eu listarei algumas referências que me levaram à esta conclusão.

- [Infinite Scrolling: Let’s Get To The Bottom Of This](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/infinite-scrolling-lets-get-to-the-bottom-of-this/)
- [Complexities of an Infinite Scroller - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/infinite-scroller)
- [Infinite Scrolling, Pagination Or “Load More” Buttons? Usability Findings In eCommerce](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/pagination-infinite-scrolling-load-more-buttons/)
- [Infinite Scrolling: Is It Good or Bad for Your Website?](https://designmodo.com/infinite-scrolling/)
- [Pavination Vs. Infinite Scroll in Datagrids](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/91615)
- [Scroll-able website vs infinite scroll website](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/91835)

Answer (score 5):

Hoje o scroll é uma tendência cada vez maior. Rolar o site não é mais um problema como antigamente - as pessoas estão mais habituadas.

A possibilidade de deixar todos os posts conforme a demanda é uma solução interessante para os usuários, e acredito que sem muita carga na performance. Como o script é acionado apenas no fim da rolagem, teria o mesmo efeito de uma paginação, porém, sem mudar de página. Com isso, o tempo que a pessoa fica na página é maior - você pode se aproveitar disso, para monetizar ou fazer qualquer outra ação desejada.

Não consigo ver nenhum contra a não ser performance, que - dependendo do servidor - pode ter o efeito visual contrário. Se o loading não termina (ou demora muito), o usuário vai ter sérios problemas em continuar navegando.

Comment: O ponto do desempenho ser crítico é bem importante. Eu diria que a percepção de demora é pior na rolagem infinita do que em qualquer outro método, justamente porque o usuário tem menos sensação de controle. Muito bem observado! :) +1

Answer (score 1):

> **Em dispositivos móveis (celulares e tablets)**

O ruim da paginação em dispositivos móveis é ter que clicar em botões. Como tais dispositivos são mais baseados em toque e "arrasto do dedo sobre a tela", o scroll infinito torna a navegação mais confortável e agradável (eu diria até mais [lúdica](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=l%C3%BAdico&oq=l%C3%BAdico&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1423j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como alguns dispositivos móveis podem variar no tamanho de tela — uns maiores e outros menores —, o clique em botões pode ser uma tarefa cansativa e chata, pois além do usuário ter que "mirar" o dedo sobre o botão, quando o tamanho da tela for muito baixo, há risco de errar o toque. Além do que é muito mais confortável arrastar o dedo sem se preocupar em que posição específica da tela isso é feito, ainda mais em relação a pessoas com algum tipo de deficiência, seja visual ou motora. Ou seja, em termos de acessibilidade, o scroll infinito se mostra bem mais adequado em termos de UX nesses dispositivos.

> **Usando ponteiro (notebooks e desktops)**

Creio que o princípio seja o mesmo em relação ao dito na seção "*dispositivos móveis*" acima.

Usando o *mouse wheel* se torna bem mais confortável o scroll infinito do que ter que clicar em botões.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas também creio que isso seja muito relativo ao público alvo e ao tipo de conteúdo do site. Muitas vezes a paginação se torna melhor porque pela quantidade de botões o usuário tem como saber a quantidade de informações disponíveis, já no scroll infinito não há como saber. O usuário vai rolando a tela e nunca sabe quando vai terminar.

---

Logo, o scroll infinito se torna melhor:

- Quando não há preocupação em saber a quantidade de informações.
- Mais confortável de navegar (principalmente em dispositivos baseados em toque).
- Quando as informações são atualizações ou uma lista onde o objetivo é mais a visualização e não muito de controle sobre elas.

Paginação:

- Quando é importante explicitar a quantidade de informações a exibir ou disponíveis.
- Quando se quer ter a possibilidade de selecionar itens em lote para alguma ação específica.
- Proporciona melhor organização e controle para o usuário.

> Entre as desvantagens tem algo que pode dar errado?

Qualquer coisa pode dar errado tanto nas vantagens quanto nas desvantagens. Confesso que não ficou muito claro esse ponto.

> Procuro informações objetivas de quem entende realmente do assunto.

"Mexo" há 20 anos com *front-end* (12 anos profissionalmente) e essa é a minha opinião e percepção do que tenho visto ao longo do tempo em que as coisas vão mudando de acordo com as atualizações e tecnologias.

Answer (score -2):

Usar scroll infinito implica assumir que o lado cliente tem bastante memória RAM e placa gráfica, o que não é verdade se for um dispositivo móvel.

O que eu já vi de Facebook dando crash no meu Android não tá escrito. Às vezes, até o Android dá crash!

Seria muito melhor ter um botão híbrido de paginação e/ou scrolling widget bem visível, na tela. Não, na verdade seria melhor nem ter botão: o padrão seria mudar de página, com uma barra de progresso mostrando quanto tempo falta para mudar a página, e, caso eu quisesse *frear* a paginação, eu seguraria o dedo no LCD.